# Angular 4 Routeguard not working when manually changing URL

Tags: angular, authentication

My angular 4 app has several routes:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: MainMenuComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Content', component: ContentComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Organisations', component: OrganisationComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Licenses', component: LicenseComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Logs', component: LogsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Community', component: CommunityComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'Signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'Login', component: SigninComponent },
  { path: 'Landing', component: LandingPageComponent},
  { path: '**', component: MainMenuComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard]}, // Page not Found
];
```

Each page with [AuthGuard] can only be activated by authenticated users.

AuthGuard looks like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

if  (this.authService.isAuthenticated)
{
  return true;
}
else
{
  this.router.navigate(['Landing']);
}
```

If a user is authenticated, the route can be visited, if not the user is redirected back to the landing page.

When pressing buttons on the website that lead to certain routes, for example:

```
<a routerLink="/Content"> Content</a>
```

The authentication works without problems, however when i manually type the route into the URL bar, the user always gets redirected back to the Landing page, even if he is authenticated.

I am trying to understand why this is happening and find out how i can fix it.

Comment: Services don't persist on page refresh. You can try using local storage or session storage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your authService is asyncronous or the session is not saved in a localStorage and when you try to get the page manually by URL your angular guard is not saving the current user.

try this:

- Change the canActivate method to work with promises
- Save your session in a localStorage or Cookie and restore the sessión when init the site if exist

```js
 
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
    // Check if the authService returns an Observable or a Promise
    
    /**
      if returns a promise change for this:
      
      this.authService.isAuthenticated.then((isAuth) => {
        if  (isAuth) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['Landing']);
        }
      })
      
      */
      
      /**
       if returns a Observable change for this:
      
      this.authService.isAuthenticated.subscribe((isAuth) => {
        if  (isAuth) {
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['Landing']);
        }
      })
      */
      if  (this.authService.isAuthenticated) {
        resolve(true);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['Landing']);
      }
   
     
    })
 }
```